# Confused by peculiar norm

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite subset of $ [0,1]$. In an exercise I am considering the norm on $P([0,1])$ (polynomials on unit interval) defined by:

$$||p||_X=\sup_X |p|$$
My question is, how do I make sense of convergent sequences under this norm?

For instance, say $X=[0,1/2]$ then a sequence $p_n$ converging to $f$ under $||\cdot||_X$ will only tell me about $f$ on $X$ and not the whole of $[0,1]$; so how can the limit $f$ be fully determined? Maybe I am missing a crucial point here...

Comment: It helps that $ f $ is restricted to be a polynomial.

Comment: @littleO Is $(P,||\cdot||_X)$ complete though? Can't the sequence converge outside the space?

Comment: $P([0,1])$ is famously *not* complete: it's dense in the set $C([0,1])$ of continuous real-valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Every $f\in C([a,b])$, continuous on a compact interval $[a,b]$, is the uniform limit of polynomials $(p_n)$ — the $p_n$ converge to $f$ with respect to the metric of the sup norm $\sup \{|f(x)\colon x\in [a,b]\}$. This is the Weierstrass approximation theorem. // However, the statement only says that "$X$ is infinite", not necessarily uncountable, not necessarily compact (closed & bounded). The "norm" so defined might be pretty badly behaved. Consider countable X.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks Brian. Yes I was aware of the theorem, but I am confused by littleO's comment - if the space is not complete w.r.t this norm how can I be sure $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: You can't "be sure" that $f$ is a polynomial because in general it won't be! if $f$ = $\sin$ on $I = [0,1]$, for example, there is a sequence of polynomials $(p_n) \to f$ uniformly w.r.t. the $\sup_I$ norm. Because $X \subseteq I$, $\sup_X \{|g(x)|\colon x\in X\} \le \sup_I\{|g(x)|\colon x\in I\}$, so $(p_n) \to f$ w.r.t. the $\sup_X$ norm too. // It's true of polynomials $p$ that if $p(x) = 0$ for all $x\in X$ then $p = 0$, just because $X$ is infinite.

Comment: @BrianO Phew, thought I was going mad. Thanks. I guess my initial question still stands then

Comment: Last thought: the $\sup_X$ "norm" behaves OK on polynomials, for the reason just mentioned. But in general it will fail to distinguish other continuous functions. E.g. if $X = \{\frac 1 n\colon n\in \mathbb{N}_+\}$, there's a continuous function $f$ that's $0$ on X but nonzero on $I\setminus X$, however the $\sup_X$ norm will think that $f = 0$. It's NOT a norm on $C([0,1])$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any normed vector space, it's impossible for a sequence to converge to two different limits.  So if we believe that $\| \cdot \|_X$ really is a norm on the vector space $P([0,1])$, then "uniqueness of limits" follows.  Of course, some Cauchy sequences won't converge to any limit at all, but that's a separate issue.

To be more concrete, suppose that $(p_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of polynomials in $P([0,1])$, and that $(p_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $p \in P([0,1])$, and also that $(p_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $q \in P([0,1])$. Then we can show that necessarily $p = q$.  One way to understand this is to note that $p$ and $q$ must agree at all points in $X$, and if two polynomials agree at infinitely many points, then the polynomials are equal.

Comment: I am confused... $||\cdot ||_X $ is definitely a norm on $P$ and a sequence in $P$ does not necessarily converge to some $p\in P$.

Comment: @user118224 That's true, I agree with you. But what's the problem with this?  Convergence of sequences makes as much sense here as it does in any normed vector space.  I think this is a good question by the way.